# Caching custom emojis from another shard

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

im trying to get a larger discord bot of mine to save all custom emojis it grabs from another shard to a cache so I can serve better response times for each shard. To give a theoretical example, my bot spawns 4 shards and only one shard serves the guild that contains all the custom emojis that I want to use across all shards. I am using this function to grab the emojis, but I need to await each one, and it can make my response times up to 15 seconds as there are many emojis I need to grab:

```
function findEmoji(id) {
    const temp = this.emojis.get(id);
    if (!temp) return null;

    const emoji = Object.assign({}, temp);
    if (emoji.guild) emoji.guild = emoji.guild.id;
    emoji.require_colons = emoji.requiresColons;

    return emoji;
  }
  async function grabEmoji(emojiID) {
    const emojiArray = await client.shard.broadcastEval(`(${findEmoji}).call(this, '${emojiID}')`);

    const foundEmoji = emojiArray.find(emoji => emoji);
    if (!foundEmoji) return;

    const raw = await client.rest.makeRequest('get', Discord.Constants.Endpoints.Guild(foundEmoji.guild).toString(), true);
    const guild =  new Discord.Guild(client, raw);
    const emoji =  new Discord.Emoji(guild, foundEmoji);

    return await emoji;
  }
// then when I send the message, I call the function with the said ID of the emoji I want:
await grabEmoji("530800350656200705");
```

On the other hand, when I remove await, it will give me listener errors (maxListeners reached) or whatever, and then display "null".

Here is what I have tried, but I havent been able to get it to work.

```
const emojiMap = new Map();
createMap();
async function createMap() {
  let woodenPick = await grabEmoji("601256699629797379"),
      stonePick  = await grabEmoji("601256431076769803"),
      ironPick=  await grabEmoji("601257055285673987"),
      goldPick = await grabEmoji("601256566670491658"),
      diamondPick= await grabEmoji("601256973798998016"),
      emeraldPick = await grabEmoji("601256896577404938"),
      rubyPick = await grabEmoji("601256312696733696"),
      ultimatePick=  await grabEmoji("629817042954092545"),
      sandstonePick = await grabEmoji("629817043142705152"),
      aquaPick = await grabEmoji("629817733902761985"),
      techPick = await grabEmoji("502940161085014046"),
      stone = await grabEmoji("502940717883064321"),
      coal = await grabEmoji("502940528149659649"),
      iron  =await grabEmoji("502940160942669824"),
      gold = await grabEmoji("493801062856392705"),
      diamond= await grabEmoji("493805522466766849"),
      obsidian  =await grabEmoji("493801062671581184"),
      emerald = await grabEmoji("630846535025819649"),
      ruby  =await grabEmoji("502940161001259018"),
      lapis = await grabEmoji("502940160988807188"),
      redstone=  await grabEmoji("632411168601931822"),
      silver = await grabEmoji("632413243503149087"),
      neonite = await grabEmoji("632413243708801024"),
      pulsatingStar=  await grabEmoji("632404511759138816"),
      sapphire = await grabEmoji("642799734192341013"),
      developerBadge = await grabEmoji("642799734209118221"),
      staffBadge = await grabEmoji("642799734209118221"),
      donatorBadge = await grabEmoji("642799734247129089"),
      contributorBadge = await grabEmoji("642799734247129089");

      emojiMap.set(['woodenPick', woodenPick])
      emojiMap.set(['stonePick', stonePick])
      emojiMap.set(['ironPick', ironPick])
      emojiMap.set(['goldPick', goldPick])
      emojiMap.set(['diamondPick', diamondPick])
      emojiMap.set(['emeraldPick', emeraldPick])
      emojiMap.set(['rubyPick', rubyPick])
      emojiMap.set(['ultimatePick', ultimatePick])
      emojiMap.set(['sandstonePick', sandstonePick])
      emojiMap.set(['aquaPick', aquaPick])
      emojiMap.set(['techPick', techPick])
      emojiMap.set(['stone', stone])
      emojiMap.set(['coal', coal])
      emojiMap.set(['iron', iron])
      emojiMap.set(['gold', gold])
      emojiMap.set(['diamond', diamond])
      emojiMap.set(['obsidian', obsidian])
      emojiMap.set(['emerald', emerald])
      emojiMap.set(['ruby', ruby])
      emojiMap.set(['lapis', lapis])
      emojiMap.set(['redstone', redstone])
      emojiMap.set(['silver', silver])
      emojiMap.set(['neonite', neonite])
      emojiMap.set(['pulsatingStar', pulsatingStar])
      emojiMap.set(['sapphire', sapphire])
      emojiMap.set(['developerBadge', developerBadge])
      emojiMap.set(['staffBadge', staffBadge])
      emojiMap.set(['donatorBadge', donatorBadge])
      emojiMap.set(['contributorBadge', contributorBadge])
}

client.on('message', ... //rest of the code continues for my command handler.

//grab emojis
  let woodenPick =   emojiMap.get('woodenPick')
  let stonePick =   emojiMap.get('stonePick')
  let ironPick =   emojiMap.get('ironPick')
  let goldPick =   emojiMap.get('goldPick')
  let diamondPick =   emojiMap.get('diamondPick')
  let emeraldPick =  emojiMap.get('emeraldPick')
  let rubyPick =   emojiMap.get('rubyPick')
  let ultimatePick =   emojiMap.get('ultimatePick')
  let sandstonePick =   emojiMap.get('sandstonePick')
  let aquaPick =   emojiMap.get('aquaPick')
  let techPick =   emojiMap.get('techPick')
  let stone =   emojiMap.get('stone')
  let coal =   emojiMap.get('coal')
  let iron =   emojiMap.get('iron')
  let gold =   emojiMap.get('gold')
  let diamond =   emojiMap.get('diamond')
  let obsidian =   emojiMap.get('obsidian')
  let emerald =   emojiMap.get('emerald')
  let ruby =   emojiMap.get('ruby')
  let lapis =   emojiMap.get('lapis')
  let redstone =   emojiMap.get('redstone')
  let silver =   emojiMap.get('silver')
  let neonite =   emojiMap.get('neonite')
  let pulsatingStar =   emojiMap.get('pulsatingStar')
  let sapphire =   emojiMap.get('sapphire')
  let developerBadge=   emojiMap.get('developerBadge')
  let staffBadge =   emojiMap.get('staffBadge')
  let donatorBadge =   emojiMap.get('donatorBadge')
  let contributorBadge =   emojiMap.get('contributorBadge')
```

Doing that returns undefined as seen here: [image: resulting message]

Does anyone have any ideas? I'm directly saving the emoji object to the map thinking I can just use it later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting discord.js's abstraction of an Emoji object in order to display it in a message is *extremely* unnecessary, but I can't blame you as discord.js tends to nudge its users towards these kinds of practices.

You **already know** the emoji names and IDs. There is no other information that you need to get from your other shards that your bot doesn't already have. In Discord messages, custom emoji are represented like this:

```
Custom Emoji            - <:NAME:ID>  -> <:mmLol:216154654256398347>

Custom Emoji (Animated) - <a:NAME:ID> -> <a:b1nzy:392938283556143104>
```

source: [discord api docs reference](https://github.com/discordapp/discord-api-docs/blob/master/docs/Reference.md)

Hence, you don't need to make any requests, any broadcast evals, or anything of the sort: you only need **static data**. Like this:

```
let emojiMap = {
  woodenPick: "601256699629797379",
  stonePick: "601256431076769803",
  //etc
};
```

I recommend a util function for putting the emoji in a message:

```
function getEmoji(name) {
  return `<:${name}:${emojiMap[name]}>`;
}
```

Use it like this:

```
await msg.react(emojiMap.woodenPick); //might need to be :name:id
//etc, probably use an array for that (or Object.keys(emojiMap))

//make embed
let description = `${getEmoji("woodenPick")} --> Wooden Pickaxe\netc...`;
```

Comment: Definitely a lot simpler this way, thank you so much!

Comment: message.react(id) doesn't seem to work across shards